# How to disable to Save Button only after value is filled on TextBox?

Tags: c#

Here The Save button must not be disabled because We need to add new values to save.

[image]

But after the existing value is loaded from DataGridView using Doubleclick event of datagridview, the save button needs to be disabled to prevent the data duplication

[image]

```
 private void Supplier_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (txtId.Text==null)
        {
            btnSave.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
```

I have tried this logic but did not work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should put the code in textbox's `TextChanged` event:

```
private void textbox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     btnSave.Enabled = !TextBox1.Text.Trim() == "";     
}
```

`.Trim()` is not needed if just whitespace is acceptable.

Textbox value cannot be null, it's enough to check if it is not equal to empty string, but if you still want to check for null value too:

```
btnSave.Enabled = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TextBox1.Text);
```

and if whitespace is acceptable

```
btnSave.Enabled = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox1.Text);
```

Comment: You are mixing the UI concepts of Save and Add New.

Comment: This has nothing to do with saving or adding new. the code shows how to enable and disable a button based on a textbox value, now OP is to choose whether to use it for save, delete, edit, ...